# using Stripes bank example UI in Swift project

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I am trying to use stripes UI example in my person swift project. I have tried to drag and drop the desired files inside of my project and update my headers and compile sources but I am still getting hit with errors I will leave screenshots below,

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

and most importantly, I am getting

[image: image 4]

I was wondering if someone has previously used Stripes BECS example UI in their own personal project and had any idea on why these issues would be popping up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Stripe per the documentation, you can't just drag and drop files in to your project: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#client-side

I'd recommend you try doing a basic example integration in a new project to figure out how the bits work, and then make use of those learnings to integrate it into your application.

Comment: Stripe is installed inside of my podfile